# conda : command is not found

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

```
$ wget "https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh"
$ chmod u+x ./Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ ./Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash
```

I ran the above commands to install Anaconda. The installation finished succesfully, but now I have this problem:

```
$ conda install fabric 
conda : command not found
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you tell the installer to execute `conda init`? Did you tell it to alter your PATH during the installation? Did you `source ~/.bashrc` after installing?  See for instance https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart and check if you followed that :)